# Disabling edit functionality using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have integrated Spring Security in my application and have defined access levels to pages in my spring-security.xml in the following format

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
<intercept-url pattern="/index" access="Admin" />
```

Now , the above mentioned pattern restricts access to a certain page, but is it possible to go to a much more granular level and restrict access by allowing all the users to view the page , but disabling the edit controls on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course. If you are using JSP than there are built-in [tag libraries](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>

<sec:authorize access="hasRole('supervisor')">
  <a href="edit">edit</a>
</sec:authorize>
```

The `edit` link will only appear if the user has `supervisor` role. There are similar solutions for other view technologies. If you are building your UI in some component framework like Wicket, just check user credentials in Java code and hide certain controls there.

However this is just the beginning. You should also enforce security on the server side by restricting either URL or Java methods (`@Secured` and friends).

Otherwise the link won't be visible, but malicious user can still discover hidden URL or perform HTTP POST using external tools.

Comment: What server side configuration need to be done to apply <sec:authorise >.

Answer (score 2):

As Tomasz wrote, Spring Security tag libraries is a good start. However, most likely you would like to protect the corresponding methods in your controllers as well (in the event that some un-authorized finds the */edit* url and calls it). The way to do it is to add the JSR-250 `@RolesAllowed` or Spring's `@Secured` annotations to your controller, e.g.

```
public class SomePageController {

    @RolesAllowed("Admin")
    public void editSomething(Map<String, String> data) {
        // only Admins reach this part
    }
}
```

Add

```
<global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled" />
```

to your Spring config for JSR-250 annotation or

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
```

for Spring's `@Secured` annotation. More info can be found in the [reference docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-method-security).

Comment: Thanks matsev for the info , i will definitely look it up and add it to my code.